# Not able find Twython.getFollowersIDs functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, ubuntu-12.04, twython

I am using Twython on Ubuntu 12.04 an when I write this line

```
twitter.getFollowersIDs(screen_name='someName')
```

I am getting this error

> AttributeError: 'Twython' object has no attribute 'getFollowersIDs'

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct method name is:

```
twitter.get_followers_ids(screen_name='someName')
```

If this is not the case please provide the output of `dir(twitter)`.

Comment: Also can you tell me how print the Screen names of user ? I am trying to do this by print but it is giving error